# "Null Bytes" error while doing a pip install on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

I have been trying to install various packages on my Windows 10 machine (like Pandas, Matlplotlib etc).

But I keep getting the same error, that is:

```
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

It stems from the following:

```
  File "c:\users\<user_name>\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 170, in get_netrc_auth
    from netrc import netrc, NetrcParseError
```

I have tried reinstalling Python, but after 1-2 installs, this error pops up again. I have no clue as to why this is happening.

What might be the reason behind this? Kindly do let me know if my question is unclear or you need more details.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+ValueError%3A+source+code+string+cannot+contain+null+bytes

Comment: Your `~/.netrc` file is in wrong encoding (perhaps UTF-16). Convert it to ASCII or UTF-8.